# How to redirect to different actionmethods by clicking on different buttons

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on this website using MVC and I want to provide my users two buttons that redirect the users to two different action methods on the same controller
here's my code on the view

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="input-group col-md-3 col-md-push-3">
                       @Html.DropDownList("HotelName", ViewBag.HotelName as SelectList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HotelAvailability.Hotel.HotelName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="input-group col-md-3 col-md-push-3 ">
                        <input type="text" name="BookingDate"  class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Enter Booking Date in dd/MM/yyyy format">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="box-footer">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-3">

                    <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success" @Url.Action("ReportPdf", "Books")>  Preview Report</button>
                    <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success" @Url.Action("GeneratePDF", "Books")>  Export to PDF</button>

                </div>

            </div>


        </div>
    }
```

as I press these buttons I want to go to the action methods with the values that the user has filled in the input field.

Comment: you can use formaction attribute HTML5 
  <button type="submit" formaction="ReportPdf">ReportPdf</button>

Answer (score 0):

putting Url.Action on the button has no effect. You haven't even put it in an attribute anyway, so it's meaningless. It's the action attribute of the form tag which controls where it's posted to. You can either

a) Add a hidden field, and use javascript to populate the value of the hidden field with something which will be meaningful to the server-side when it's posted back, depending on which button is pressed (or maybe have one button, but have a radio button field so the user can select whether they want preview or export). Then the server will decide whether to redirect to the preview or export actions and return the appropriate data.

b) Change the buttons to client-side buttons (instead of "submit" buttons). Put the URLs required properly into an attribute of each button. Handle the button click events in javascript, fetch the URL from the button's attribute, set it as the "action" attribute of the form, then use javascript to submit the form, which will then be submitted to the correct action.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `formaction` attribute HTML5

example

```
<button type="submit" formaction="Controller/action">ReportPdf</button>
<button type="submit" formaction="Controller/action">GeneratePDF</button>
```

in your case

```
<button type="submit" formaction="ReportPdf">ReportPdf</button>
<button type="submit" formaction="GeneratePDF">GeneratePDF</button>
```